# Brezis' exercise 8.8.4: how to prove $u_n \to u$ in $W^{1, 1} (I)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces

I'm trying to solve below exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> **Exercise 8.8.4** Let $I=(0,1)$ and $u \in W^{1, p} (I)$ with $p \in [1, \infty)$ and $u(0)=0$. Fix a function $\xi \in C^\infty (\mathbb R)$ such that $\xi (x)=0$ for $x \le 1$ and $\xi (x)=1$ for $x \ge 2$. Let $\xi_n (x) := \xi (nx)$ and $u_n (x) = \xi_n (x) u(x)$.
>
> 1. Check that $u_n \in W^{1, p} (I)$.
> 2. Prove that $u_n \to u$ in $W^{1, p} (I)$.

In my below attempt, I can prove $(2)$ for $p \in (1, \infty)$. Could you explain how to prove it for $p=1$?

---

First, we have $\| \xi_n \|_\infty = \| \xi \|_\infty$ for all $n$. Second, $\xi_n (x)=0$ for $x \le \frac{1}{n}$ and $\xi (x)=1$ for $x \ge \frac{2}{n}$. Then $\xi_n \to 1$ everywhere on $(0, 1)$ and $\|\xi_n-1 \|_q \to 0$ for $q \in [1, \infty)$.

Second, $\xi_n' (x) = n\xi' (nx)$. Then $\xi_n' (x)=0$ for $x < \frac{1}{n}$ and for $x > \frac{2}{n}$. Then $\xi'_n \to 0$ everywhere on $(0, 1)$.

Third, $u'_n (x) = \xi_n' (x) u(x) + \xi_n (x) u'(x)$. Clearly, $u'_n \to u'$ everywhere on $(0, 1)$.

1.

Clearly, $\xi_n \in W^{1, p} (I)$ for all $n$. Then $u_n \in W^{1, p} (I)$ by below result (in the same book), i.e.,

> **Corollary 8.10** Let $I$ be a (possibly unbounded) open interval of $\mathbb R$. Let $u, v \in W^{1, p}(I)$ with $1 \leq p \leq$ $\infty$. Then $u v \in W^{1, p}(I)$ and  $(u v)^{\prime}=u^{\prime} v+u v^{\prime}$. Furthermore, the formula for integration by parts holds:
> $$
> \int_y^x u^{\prime} v=u(x) v(x)-u(y) v(y)-\int_y^x u v^{\prime} \quad \forall x, y \in \bar{I} .
> $$

2. 

Clearly, $u_n \to u$ everywhere on $(0, 1)$. By dominated convergence theorem, $u_n \to u$ in $L^p$. It remains to prove that $u'_n \to u'$ in $L^p$. It suffices to prove
$$
I_n = \| \xi_n' u \|_p^p = \int_0^1 |n\xi' (nx)u(x)|^p dx = \int_0^{2/n} |n\xi' (nx)u(x)|^p dx \to 0.
$$

Then
$$
\begin{align*}
I_n &= \int_0^1 |n\xi' (nx)u(x)|^p dx \\
&= \int_0^{2/n} |nx\xi' (nx)|^p\left  | \frac{u(x)}{x} \right |^p dx \\
&\le 2 \| \xi' \|_{L^\infty (I)} \int_0^{2/n} \left  | \frac{u(x)}{x} \right |^p dx.
\end{align*}
$$

By **Exercise 8.8.1** (in the same book), $u(0)=0$ and $p \in (1, \infty)$ implies
$$
\left\|\frac{u(x)}{x}\right\|_{L^p(I)} \leq \frac{p}{p-1}\left\|u^{\prime}\right\|_{L^p(I)},
$$
and thus
$$
\int_0^{2/n} \left  | \frac{u(x)}{x} \right |^p dx \to 0.
$$

Then it remains to prove for the case $p=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p=1$. Then

$$
\begin{align*}
I_n &= \int_0^1 |n\xi' (nx)u(x)| dx \\
&= \int_0^{2/n} |n\xi' (nx)u(x)| dx \\
&\le n \| \xi' \|_{L^\infty (0, 2)} \int_0^{2/n} |u(x)| dx \\
&\le 2\| \xi' \|_{L^\infty (0, 2)} \sup_{x\in (0,\frac{2}{n})} |u(x)|.
\end{align*}
$$

Because $u \in C (\bar I)$ and $u(0)=0$, we get
$$
\sup_{x\in (0,\frac{2}{n})} |u(x)| \to 0.
$$

The claim then follows.