# Brezis' exercise 8.9.3: check that $u_n \in W^{2, p}(I)$ and $u_n \rightarrow u$ in $W^{2, p}(I)$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, sobolev-spaces

Let $I=(0,1)$. I'm trying to solve below exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> **Exercise 8.9**
>
> 1. Let $u \in W^{2, p}(I)$ with $1<p<\infty$. Assume that $u(0)=u^{\prime}(0)=0$. Show that $\frac{u(x)}{x^2} \in L^p(I)$ and $\frac{u^{\prime}(x)}{x} \in L^p(I)$ with
>    (1)
>    $$
>    \left\|\frac{u(x)}{x^2}\right\|_{L^p(I)}+\left\|\frac{u^{\prime}(x)}{x}\right\|_{L^p(I)} \leq C_p\left\|u^{\prime \prime}\right\|_{L^p(I)}
>    $$
> 2. Deduce that $v(x)=\frac{u(x)}{x} \in W^{1, p}(I)$ with $v(0)=0$.
> 3. Let $u$ be as in question $(1)$. Set $u_n=\zeta_n u$, where $\zeta_n$ is defined in question 4 of **Exercise 8.8**. Check that $u_n \in W^{2, p}(I)$ and $u_n \rightarrow u$ in $W^{2, p}(I)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in my below attempt of $(3)$. Could you please have a check on it?

---

We need an auxiliary result (in the same book), i.e.,

> **Exercise 8.8:**
>
> 1. Let $u \in W^{1, p}(0,1)$ with $1<p<\infty$. Show that if $u(0)=0$, then $\frac{u(x)}{x} \in L^p(0,1)$ and
>    $$
>    \left\|\frac{u(x)}{x}\right\|_{L^p(0,1)} \leq \frac{p}{p-1}\left\|u^{\prime}\right\|_{L^p(0,1)} .
>    $$
> 2. Conversely, assume that $u \in W^{1, p}(0,1)$ with $1 \leq p<\infty$ and that $\frac{u(x)}{x} \in$ $L^p(0,1)$. Show that $u(0)=0$.
> 3. Let $u(x)=(1+|\log x|)^{-1}$. Check that $u \in W^{1,1}(0,1), u(0)=0$, but $\frac{u(x)}{x} \notin$ $L^1(0,1)$.
> 4. Let $I=(0,1)$ and $u \in W^{1, p} (I)$ with $p \in [1, \infty)$ and $u(0)=0$. Fix a function $\xi \in C^\infty (\mathbb R)$ such that $\xi (x)=0$ for $x \le 1$ and $\xi (x)=1$ for $x \ge 2$. Let $\xi_n (x) := \xi (nx)$ and $u_n (x) = \xi_n (x) u(x)$. Check that $u_n \in W^{1, p} (I)$ and that $u_n \to u$ in $W^{1, p} (I)$.

We have
$$
\begin{align*}
u_n &= \xi_n u, \\
u'_n &= \xi'_n u + \xi_n u',, \\
u''_n &= \xi''_n u + 2 \xi'_n u' + \xi_n u''. \\
\end{align*}
$$

It follows from $\xi''_n, \xi'_n, \xi_n \in L^\infty (I)$ and $u, u', u'' \in L^p (I)$ that $u_n, u'_n, u''_n \in L^p (I)$. Then $u_n \in W^{2, p}(I)$.

We have $u, u' \in W^{1, p}(I)$. By **Exercise 8.9.4**, $u_n \rightarrow u$ in $W^{1, p}(I)$. It remains to prove $u''_n \rightarrow u''$ in $L^{p}(I)$. We have $\xi_n \to 1$ everywhere on $(0, 1)$. Then $\xi_n u'' \to u''$ in $L^{p}(I)$. I already [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4786480/brezis-exercise-8-8-4-how-to-prove-u-n-to-u-in-w1-1-i) that $u(0)$ implies $\xi_n' u \to 0$ in $L^{p}(I)$. Notice that $u'(0)=0$. With similar reasoning, we can prove that $\xi''_n u \to 0$ and $\xi'_n u' \to 0$ in $L^{p}(I)$. It follows that $u''_n \rightarrow u''$ in $L^{p}(I)$.